# jQuery AJAX multiple calls error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to handling errors. Here is my case - I have multiple AJAX calls from different urls. I want when some url response error 500 to know which url is. Here is my code.

```
var urls = ["url1.php", "url2.php", "url3.php"];
$.each(urls, function(index, value) {
    $.ajax({
        global: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: value,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: returnData(),
        success: function(result) {
            switch(value) {
                case "url1.php":
                    break;
                case "url2.php":
                    break;
                case "url3.php":
                    break;
            }
        },
        error: function (e, request, status, error) {
            if (e.status == 500) {
                alert("500 error");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now when one of them return error 500 I cannot know which url is.
I will be very grateful if someone give advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be in 'request' ?

Comment: @biseibutsu okay, but how? Did u have idea?

Comment: You can try to find the url in the request from your browser's developer tools, you should be able to see the request itself.

Comment: @biseibutsu Yes, I know this. But I want to show url in error message.

Comment: Found it, you can get the url from $(this), in the error function scope. I have it with `$(this)[0].url`

Comment: @biseibutsu can u be more specifically where in my code ?

Comment: Use the variable "value"?

Comment: @epascarello, I don't think it can be used, when the ajax is being executed the javascript function probably have already executed.

Comment: The variable would be able to be referenced... heck the success method is using it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Since I can not delete this answer because it is the accepted answer; This is not the better answer, please refer to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686481/2375899)'s answer, using the `value` variable.

You s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶  may it like this:

```
        error: function (e, request, status, error) {
            if (e.status == 500) {
                alert("500 error" + $(this)[0].url);
            }
        }
```

You might need to debug to make sure of `$(this)[0].url` part, I was just checking where to find the url in the error callback in my code somewhere, it might not be the same for you? I am not sure. But you should be able to find the url in $(this) object.

Comment: Thnaks a lot! Works great!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: Does this really work? `this` shouldn't be passed through to the callback function.

Comment: @Barmar, It does work; but It might not be the best solution, could you let me know why `this` should not be passed? I am just accessing it. Using `value` looks a lot cleaner and better to be honest, but I thought it would be undefined.

Comment: @biseibutsu `this` is not captured in closures unless you use ES6 fat-arrow functions. There's nothing in the `$.ajax` documentation that says that jQuery explicitly uses `this` as the context when calling the `error` function.

Comment: `value`, on the other hand, is an ordinary variable. Since it's a local variable to each `$.each` callback function, they'll each have their own binding of the variable, which will be saved in the closure.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for explaining, I thought `value` would be undefined, but now I see, my answer is handling the situation in an unnecessary way.

Answer (score 2):

The `value` variable will be captured in the closure. So do:

```
alert("500 error from " + value);
```

Comment: This is the much better answer than the one from @biseibutsu